# How to determine size of IEnumerable in bytes in order to get a good batch size?

Tags: c#, csv, ienumerable, csvhelper

I'm writing records into a csv format in order to upload it as a file through an external API that has a file size limit on the uploads. My method for writing records to memory looks like this:

```
using CsvHelper;

public async Task<byte[]> WriteToMemoryAsync<T>(IEnumerable<T> recordsToWrite) where T : class
{
    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(memoryStream))
        using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, new CultureInfo("sv-SE")))
        {
            await csv.WriteRecordsAsync(recordsToWrite);

        }
        return memoryStream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

My current approach for batching looks like this:

```
public async Task<Dictionary<int, byte[]>> BatchWriteToMemoryAsync<T>(IEnumerable<T> recordsToWrite) where T : class
{
    var maxBatchSize = 50_000;

    var nrOfBatches = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)recordsToWrite.Count() / maxBatchSize);

    Dictionary<int, byte[]> records = new();
    for (int batchNr = 0; batchNr < nrOfBatches; batchNr++)
    {
        records.Add(batchNr, await WriteToMemoryAsync<T>(recordsToWrite));
    }

    return records;
}
```

The problem is that the batch size is sort of arbitrary. Depending on how large objects `T` includes this might fail.

> Is there any way to get the size in bytes of the `IEnumerable<T>` in order to get an approximation of the file size and then determine the number of batches based on this?

> Is there any other way to approach this?

### Edit

---

I've now implemented the first solution that Magnus suggested. However, there is a problem with flushing the written record before checking the length of the stream as the stream has already passed the size limit at that point.

I created a test to simulate the problem and this fails as the batch size hits 1009B for the first batch.

```
[Fact]
public void WhenWritingToMemoryInBatches_ShouldEnsureFileSizeDoesNotExceedLimit()
{
    //Arrange
    var records = GenerateTestRecords(100);

    var fileSizeLimit = 1_000;  //1000B limit

    var csvHandler = new CsvHandler();

    //Act
    var file = csvHandler.BatchWriteToMemory(records, fileSizeLimit);

    //Assert
    Assert.All(file, f => Assert.True(f.Length < fileSizeLimit, $"Expected fileSize to be less than {fileSizeLimit}. Actual fileSize was {f.Length}."));
}

private IEnumerable<TestRecord> GenerateTestRecords(int amountOfRecords)
{
    List<TestRecord> records = new();
    for (int i = 0; i < amountOfRecords; i++)
    {
        records.Add(new TestRecord
        {
            StringType = $"String {i}",
            IntType = 1,
        });
    }
    return records;
}

private class TestRecord
{
    public string? StringType { get; set; }
    public int IntType { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: There's no way of getting the size of an `IEnumerable` without enumerating it. The `ICollection` interface extends `IEnumerable` and adds a `Count` property, so you'd need at least that. Some `IEnumerable` objects don't actually contain any data until you start enumerating them, e.g. LINQ queries. Any iterator generally reads the data as it goes, so you'd have to actually read all the data to get the item count, then you'd have to read it all a second time to get the data itself.

Comment: Ok, but if I would accept an ICollection instead and get the count I would still not get an approximation of the file size right? Then I would just get the amount of entries but have no idea of the byte size of the collection?

Comment: Serialize each element, then you know the byte size. Then you can accumulate those as long as the sum of bytes is below threshold. If it exceeds then it's time for a new file. This way, you won't know the batch size in advance, but you also do not need to. Just continue until there are no more elements.

Comment: Since you are writing the entities to memory, does that mean that they are being marshalled? If so you can use `Marshal.SizeOf<T>();` to determine the size of each entity when it would be marshalled.

Comment: @Fildor Would serialization imply a considerable performance hit compared to Magnus' suggested approach of checking the stream size instead?

Comment: @MatthewWatson Not sure if I completely understand how marshalling differs from serialization in this context? I'm passing around a ``byte[] fileToExport`` and eventually adding it as a formdata field to an API-call as such: ``formdata.Add(new StringContent(Encoding.Default.GetString(fileToExport)), "file")``

Comment: Marshalling requires that the type being marshalled is blittable (contains only structs and plain data types)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if instead send all your items to `WriteToMemory` and then check the size of the stream and if of desired size return the items written and initialize a new stream for the next batch. So `WriteToMemory` will return a set of batches instead.
You might not want to flush after every written record, find an appropriate flush interval.

```
public static IEnumerable<byte[]> WriteToMemory<T>(IEnumerable<T> recordsToWrite)
{
    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    var writer = new StreamWriter(memoryStream);
    var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, new CultureInfo("sv-SE"));

    try
    {
        foreach (var r in recordsToWrite)
        {
            csv.WriteRecord(r);
            csv.Flush(); //might want to flush after every x items instead of each.
            if (memoryStream.Length >= 1024)
            {
                csv.Dispose();
                writer.Dispose();
                memoryStream.Dispose();
                
                yield return memoryStream.ToArray();
                
                memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                writer = new StreamWriter(memoryStream);
                csv = new CsvWriter(writer, new CultureInfo("sv-SE"));
            }
        }
        
        csv.Flush();
        if (memoryStream.Length > 0)
            yield return memoryStream.ToArray();
    }
    finally
    {
        csv.Dispose();
        writer.Dispose();
        memoryStream.Dispose();
    }
}
```

To avoid holding large amounts of byte arrays in memory you can instead take in a delegate to your method to create the stream (for example a file on disk).

```
public class Program
{
    private static int count = 0;
    public static async Task Main()
    {
        await WriteToStreamAsync(Enumerable.Range(0, 10_000), () => File.Create($"C:\\temp\\\\files\\file{count++}.csv"));
    }

    public static async Task WriteToStreamAsync<T>(IEnumerable<T> recordsToWrite, Func<Stream> createFile)
    {
        var stream = createFile();
        var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
        var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, new CultureInfo("sv-SE"));

        try
        {
            var i = 0;
            foreach (var r in recordsToWrite)
            {
                csv.WriteRecord(r);
                if (++i % 100 == 0) //Find some good interval
                    await csv.FlushAsync();
                if (stream.Length >= 1024)
                {
                    await csv.DisposeAsync();
                    await writer.DisposeAsync();
                    await stream.DisposeAsync();
                    
                    stream = createFile();
                    writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
                    csv = new CsvWriter(writer, new CultureInfo("sv-SE"));
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            await csv.DisposeAsync();
            await writer.DisposeAsync();
            await stream.DisposeAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That was a very neat solution with yielding back chunks of the written records!

Comment: What should the flush interval be based on? Just trial and error by testing different values or is there anything more tangible to grasp for?

Comment: Yeh, you would have to try some different values and see how it impacts performance.

Comment: I encountered a problem as the ``if (memoryStream.Length >= 1024)`` check is done after the flush and thus the last record makes the filesize larger than the limit. Any suggestions as to how to solve that?

Comment: I added a unit test to my post for the batch method indicating the problem.

Comment: Make the size a few kb smaller than the limit. In theory a single record might exceed the limit.